# Is creating multiple tables faster than a single table for MySql

Tags: mysql, sql

I use MySql to store different google map markers for different cities.

My question is:

Would it be faster if I created different tables for each cities and store the latitude, longitude there.
OR would I be fine with creating a single table to store all the markers there, add a city value column and retrieve them by the city name on my website.

If I create a single table I could end up with 300.000+ rows, on the other hand if I create different tables for each cities, I could end up with 500+ tables...

My immediate thought of process would think multiple tables with less rows would be faster, but it will be a huge mess.

Thank you.

Comment: One table only. Indexed properly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, no, no.  Databases are optimized to handle fewer bigger tables, rather than many smaller tables.  Maintaining separate parallel tables is a maintenance nightmare.  Here are some reasons:

- You can't declare foreign key constraints.
- Adding a column, contraint, or index requires changing many tables.
- The tables are inefficient, because of the proliferation of half-filled pages.
- Queries over *all* the data are a nightmare.

You have an entity.  Follow the best practice of having one table for that entity.